# distinguish between radio buttons in vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm building an application which has a few radio buttons and based on the selection the user makes I have to do one thing or another. Now I've used an OptionGroup to create the radio buttons but I don't seem to be able to understand how I can differentiate between radio buttons. In pure java it's pretty straightforward as I would create each radio button and then group them together with a ButtonGroup object but in vaadin I really don't know. The documentation is as usual abysmal, so I'm a bit stuck. Here is some code for you:

```
    public class ConverterComponent extends CustomComponent{

    private TextField name2 = new TextField();
    private OptionGroup single;
    private TextField userInput;
    private TextField result;
    private Button submit;
    private Button reset;
    private static final String conversion1 = "Km to miles";
    private static final String conversion2 = "Miles to Km";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public ConverterComponent(){
        submit = new Button("Submit");
        reset = new Button("Reset");
        result = new TextField();
        userInput = new TextField();
        result.setEnabled(false);
        result.setVisible(false);
        userInput.setVisible(false);
        reset.setVisible(false);
        submit.setVisible(false);

        single = new OptionGroup("Select the conversion");
        single.addItems(conversion1, conversion2);

        reset.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener(){          
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event){
                clearFields();      
                getResult().setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        submit.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener(){         
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {             
                getResult().setVisible(true);
                //NEED TO KNOW WHICH RADIO BUTTON HAS BEEM CLICKED SO THAT i CAN DECIDE WHICH CONVERSION TO USE

            }
        });

        single.addValueChangeListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener(){           
            @Override
            public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
                clearFields();
                /*System.out.println("You chose: " + event.getProperty().getValue().toString() + "\n");
                System.out.println("other line " + event.getProperty() + "\n" + " id is " + single.getId() + " size " + single.size());*/

                //System.out.println("event is " + event.getProperty().getValue());                     

                switch(event.getProperty().getValue().toString()){
                case conversion1:
                    System.out.println(conversion1);
                    break;
                case conversion2:
                    System.out.println(conversion2);
                    break;
                }
                displayFields();

            }
        });
    }   
    public OptionGroup getRadioButtons(){
        return single;
    }
    public TextField getResult(){
        return result;
    }
    public TextField getUserInput(){
        return userInput;
    }
    public void displayFields(){
        //getResult().setVisible(true);
        getUserInput().setVisible(true);
        getResetButton().setVisible(true);
        getSubmitButton().setVisible(true);
    }
    public Button getResetButton(){
        return reset;
    }
    public Button getSubmitButton(){
        return submit;
    }
    public void clearFields(){
        getResult().setValue("");
        getUserInput().setValue("");
    }
    public void validateInputs(){


    }
}
```

Bear in mind that I have to add more options in the future, but what I'm trying to get to is, when the the user selects a radio button, no matter which, he will get two input boxes one for his input and the other one - read only - displaying the conversion. The point is that when the selection is made and the input boxes are displayed I have to know already what selection the user has made because I have to be able to grab the input and convert it correctly. In the code above I'm displaying the user's choice but I don't have anything to check it or compare it to. Ideally what I would like to do is: 
-click the first radio button
-determine which radio button has been selected so I know which conversion to use.

Comment: Have you seenn this docu? https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-optiongroup.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use any objects as item ids in Vaadin. For example you could do something like this:

If you for example have an enum presenting different conversions

```
    public enum Conversion {
        KM_TO_MILES,
        MILES_TO_KM
    }
```

then you could do something like this:

```
        OptionGroup optionGroup = new OptionGroup();

        optionGroup.addItem(Conversion.KM_TO_MILES);
        optionGroup.setItemCaption(Conversion.KM_TO_MILES, "Km to miles");

        optionGroup.addItem(Conversion.MILES_TO_KM);
        optionGroup.setItemCaption(Conversion.MILES_TO_KM, "Miles to Km");

        optionGroup.addValueChangeListener(e -> {
            if (e.getProperty().getValue() == Conversion.KM_TO_MILES) {
                // km to miles selected
            }
        });
```

Comment: HI guys, thanks I think I understand. I modified my code to reflect your suggestions (I hope), but I'm still a bit puzzled. I've updated the code at the beginning of the thread.
The thing is this code works now but what happens if we change the name of the elements when I declare them in `single.addItems("Km to miles", "Miles to Km");`? Things will break, so perhaps it's worth copying somehow, the element in a variable and then use that for the comparison, is that possible?

Comment: +antobbo maybe you should post more code to your question.

Comment: right, I updated the code as requested, but I think I figured out a good way to do it

Comment: I run into another problem, still with the radio buttons of course. You might know the application is supposed to make conversions, like Km to miles etc. I can choose which selection to make with radio buttons and then I have a submit button which, when clicked, will make the conversion. When the button is clicked I have know which radio button is selected because based on that I will know which conversion to use. The problem is that from within the `buttonClick()` I can't access the `event.getProperty().getValue().toString()` of the radio button. How woudl I do it? I've updated the code above